# Google Translate API v3: how to authenticate with private_key from Service Account Key?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-translate, google-translation-api

How to authenticate to Google Translate API v3 with private_key from Service Account Key?
As v3 doesn't work with api keys there should be a way of authentication but with private_key

Comment: If you don't want to upload credentials onto every server, how *do* you want to authenticate? You'll need *some* sort of authentication information. You could potentially fetch the credentials from some central server within your network, but without more details about what sort of thing you *would* find acceptable, it's hard to give any more information.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your reply! I don't want to upload a json with service account key on each of our hundreds machines. I needed a solution where I can use something similar to an api key as for v3 google doesn't provide possibility to use api keys. I couldn't find documentation for the solution I provided. I figured that out by looking into interface of TranslationServiceClient

Comment: What do you see as the fundamental difference between an API key and a service account file, other than length? If you've got the ability to propagate an API key, can't you use that ability to propagate the service account file content? (I believe all libraries allow you to specify that as a string in code, rather than it being an actual file.)

Comment: @JonSkeet From the official documentation it's not obvious that it's possible to treat a service account file as an API key. If you find and share the link it would be really great and helpful

Comment: It's not a matter of treating it as an API key. It's a matter of "both are just text - if you can get an API key to all of your servers, you should be able to get a service account to them in a similar way". If you need help using the service account JSON content without actually saving it anywhere, please specify in the question which language you're using. (I can't consult my colleagues at the moment as I'm on vacation, but I may be able to work it out - or let you know when I'm back from vacation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { TranslationServiceClient } from '@google-cloud/translate';

const credentials = {
 client_email: <your_service_account_email>,
 private_key: <your_private_key_from_service_account_key>
};

const translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient({
    credentials,
});

// now you can use translationClient to perform translations
```